# Is there a way to authenticate with fingerprint on android without showing the dialog?

Tags: android, react-native, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I am integrating the fingerprint authentication functionality in react-native, and while I was coding the Android implementation I saw that FingerprintManager forces you to display a dialog when authenticating. I do not want to display a dialog, i'd need an Icon that would tell the user that he can login with the fingerprint. The user puts the finger on the sensor and logs in. With that said, the sensor should be listening for the fingerprint if the user has Fingeprint Login enabled, and trigger the authentication as soon as the fingerprint is detected and valid. 
Does someone know any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about react-native, but I use this library and its great. com.multidots:fingerprint-auth:1.0.1. It doesn't display the android's native dialog and you get method after implementing the Interface FingerPrintAuthCallback.
https://bintray.com/multidots/md-maven/fingerprint-auth#

Comment: Only the new `BiometricPrompt` API shows its own UI. The old `FingerprintManager` API doesn't show any UI and doesn't force you to show any UI either. However, you may receive hints during the authentication process (e.g. to tell the user to keep their finger still on the sensor), and not being able to present those to the user could lead to a poor user experience.